# Image moving on the screen when I change its size

Tags: html, css, image

Here's my site: https://katekarate.github.io/My-Site/.

The cloud image is ok, but the rainbow image is moving when I change the window size. I'm just a beginner and don't understand why it is happening.. please, help!

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Charmonman', cursive;
  font-size: 5.6rem;
  color: #11999E;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #11999E;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #30E3CA;
}

a {
  color: #30E3CA;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #E4F9F5;
}

hr {
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: 7px dotted #EAF6F6;
  width: 5%;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #E4F9F5;
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-container {
  background-color: #11999E;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
}

.contact-me {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  line-height: 2;
}

.footer-end {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.top-cloud {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.bottom-cloud {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 300px;
  right: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.skill-row {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 2;
}

.profile-img {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.coding-img {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.teacher-img {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.btn {
  background: #11cdd4;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #11999e);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #11999e);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #11999e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #11cdd4, #11999e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #11cdd4, #11999e);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8;
  -moz-border-radius: 8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #30e3cb;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #2bc4ad);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #2bc4ad);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #2bc4ad);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #30e3cb, #2bc4ad);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #30e3cb, #2bc4ad);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<title>Kate Hyrenko</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Charmonman&amp;family=Merriweather&amp;family=Montserrat&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud1.png" alt="cloud1-img">
  <h1>I'm Kate .</h1>
  <h2>a web developer.</h2>
  <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
  <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
</div>
<div class="middle-container">
  <div class="profile">
    <img class="profile-img" src="images/girl.png" alt="profile-img">
    <h2>Hello.</h2>
    <p>I am actually an ESL teacher, who has just become a web developer.</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="skills">
    <h2>My Skills.</h2>
    <div class="skill-row">
      <img class="coding-img" src="images/coding.png" alt="coding-img">
      <h3>Coding &amp; debugging</h3>
      <p>I am really interested in coding! I like HTML and CSS. I don’t understand JavaScript just yet, but I’m on my way to excellence. I like debugging my own work, because I can fix all my mistakes by my own!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="skill-row">
      <img class="teacher-img" src="images/teacher.png" alt="teacher-img">
      <h3>Educating developing minds</h3>
      <p>Yes, it is stressful to be a teacher, yes I often complained, yes there’s a lot of work you have to do at home… But you can change someone’s life and teach kindness and compassion. It’s a priceless experience.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="contact-me">
    <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
    <h3>I’m currently available for freelance work or internship.</h3>
    <p>If you are looking for someone who is still learning or just want to say hey, get in touch!</p>
    <a class="btn" href="mailto:katya.gyrenko@gmail.com">CONTACT ME</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-container">
  <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kate-hyrenko-30116a177/">LinkedIn</a>
  <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.instagram.com/katya_gyrenko/">Instagram</a>
  <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/katya.gyrenko/">Facebook</a>
  <p class="footer-end">© 2022 Kate Hyrenko</p>
</div>
<div style="position: static !important;"></div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I made a snippet of your code but beware the images display the alt since the references are somewhat broken herein

Comment: Please state your desired results as clearly as possible so we do not guess improperly.  Note I changed the image alt so we would properly discuss which "cloud"  There is likely a much cleaner way to do what you want here

Comment: Curious what is the intended purpose of `<div style="position: static !important;"></div>` at the bottom of the HTML there?  Also no need for multiple `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">`

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace your code with this? And you should use [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

```css
.bottom-cloud {
    position: relative;
    right: 250px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 250px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
    <img class="bottom-cloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <img class="top-cloud" src="images/cloud1.png" alt="cloud-img">
    <h1>I'm Kate .</h1>
    <h2>a web developer.</h2>
    <img src="images/mountain.png" alt="mountain-img">
</div>
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the advice! I have just started coding, so I appreciate all the advice! this code seems to just reposition the rainbow cloud and it's still moving when I change screen size(

Answer (score 0):

**The fix** I think the easiest fix you can apply is to use `absolute` position instead of `relative` on your `rainbow` image.

```css
.bottom-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 400px);
}
```

With position `absolute` the element will be positioned relatively to its parent `relative` container. (With `relative` it's positioned relatively to its own initial position, which my change during screen resize)

**The problem** The problem is that `.bottom-cloud` is on relative position, that means when the initial position of that element is changed then the image will be shifted as well.

In your html you have 2 images - `rainbow` and `mountain`.
On a big screen they are going to be rendered in a single row, but on a small screens the images will break in 2 lines, and then your `bottom`,  `right` values are not valid anymore:

```
<!--
  big screen, 
  images in a single line, 
  `bottom` and `right` configured correctly
-->
<img>rainbow</img> <img>mountain</img> 


<!--
  small screen,
  images in 2 lines now as there is not enough space to keep them in a single line,
  now `bottom` and `right` configured incorrectly, because initial position of the rainbow element was changed
-->
<img>rainbow</img>
<img>mountain</img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the image does not move until the screen size is smaller than 770px. Is there a media query involved that sets a breakpoint?

Not quite sure what you want to achieve but you could handle the image position differently on smaller screens by adding the following additional CSS.

Learn more about [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

In this example, I center the image when the screen size is below 770px:

```
@media (max-width: 770px) {
  .button-cloud {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

I just googled and found these recommended break points:

- 576px for portrait phones.
- 768px for tablets.
- 992px for laptops.
- 1200px for large devices.